# How to do I create array with multiple set of bytes to use with for each loop fucntion

Tags: c#

C# Question:
I need to be able to create array of sets of bytes with a variable assigned to each set of bytes return that set of bytes to go through a for each loop function until the list is finished for example:

```
 public static bytes[] OBJECTS()
        {
            return new bytes[3]
      {
        public static byte[] object1 = new byte[] { 0xB7, 0x79, 0xA0, 0x91 };
        public static byte[] object2 = new byte[] { 0x4C, 0x80, 0xEB, 0x0E };
        public static byte[] object3 = new byte[] { 0x5D, 0x0A, 0xAC, 0x8F };
      };
        } 


                        EXAMPLE
    I need to be able to return every value in the array to the for loop to perform functions with every set of bytes. Sorry for the confusion. 

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
                {
        1st Loop Return Object 1  
        2st Loop Return Object 2  
        3rd Loop Return Object 3  
                }
```

Comment: Can you do what need with [nested loops](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_nested_loops.htm)?

Comment: The "sample code" doesn't really make much sense to me.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @David I need to be able to return every value in the array to the for loop to perform functions with every set of bytes. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This code most closely resembles the code in your question, but this is legal C#. How close is this to what you want?

```
void Main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        byte[] selected = OBJECTS()[i];
        /* do something with `selected` */
    }
}

public static byte[][] OBJECTS()
{
    return new byte[][]
    {
        new byte[] { 0xB7, 0x79, 0xA0, 0x91 },
        new byte[] { 0x4C, 0x80, 0xEB, 0x0E },
        new byte[] { 0x5D, 0x0A, 0xAC, 0x8F },
    };
}
```

This would be a better way to get each sub-array:

```
foreach (byte[] selected in OBJECTS())
{
    /* do something with `selected` */
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed.  Thanks so much

Comment: @OFFSETGHOST - No worries.